# Chemical breakdown of sunflower seed to determine the allergy-causing substance

Tags: organic-chemistry

I have a severe anaphylactic reaction if I ingest a sunflower seed, and carry an Epi-Pen at all times. What is it in the seed kernel that could be so problematic and is it going to also be present in sunflower oil and in the sunflower organic derivatives used so much now in lotions, shampoo, and many other products today? I try to avoid any food or product that states that it contains sunflower in any form but it is becoming more difficult to avoid, especially when many crackers and such state "may contain sunflower or canola or other" oils. I even fear putting lotion on that might contain it!

Comment: Personal medical questions are off limits on the site. This is a life threatening problem and you should certainly consult an allergist to discuss this problem. Don't solicit advice from us nitwits.

Comment: @MaxW, this seems to me like purely a question of curiosity, and nothing in the question suggests that the OP intends to take any action based on any answer.  The fact that she's had severe anaphylactic reactions in the past and carries medication to control it suggests she's seen / is seeing a doctor about this.  At least that's my take.  If this is the case (Theresa W. Moore please comment on this) do you think the personal medical question policy applies? The definition [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is pretty brief.  Are you sure this violates that policy?

Comment: @airhuff yes I'm sure. I certainly don't want to offer an opinion if the chemical that is in the seed is not in the oil so the oil is safe. She should absolutely have that conversation with her allergist not us.

Comment: @MaxW, yeah, I guess any chance the OP would act on our advice is definitely just not worth it.